# Inverse image of this set?

Tags: functions

Suppose that we have a function $f$ $:$ $X$ $\to$ $Y$, with

$ X $ $=$ {1,2,3,4,5,6}
$Y$ $=$ {a,b}

define $$
f(x) = \left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
      a & \mbox{if $x =1$ OR $2 $ OR 3} \\
      b & \mbox{if $ x = 4 $ OR 5 OR 6} \
   \end{array}\right.
$$ 
my question is, when we take the f inverse of {a,b} will we get {1,2,3,4,5,6} OR {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}} ?

**Edited**: I also have another doubt, do $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}$({$a$}) mean the same?

Comment: $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ -- I will let someone give more details on why in a real answer because I'm about to board a plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preimage or [inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) of the set $Y=\{a,b\}$

is the subset of $X$ defined by $f^{-1}(Y)=\{x\in X|f(x)\in Y$},

which in this case is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}=X$.

Comment: I also have another doubt, do $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}$({$a$}) mean the same?

Comment: $f^{-1} $ could mean inverse function, which is not well-defined in this case

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A:=${$a$}; $B:=${$b$}; $A \cup B=${$a,b$}.

$f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}$({$a$})$=$

{$1,2,3$}$\subset ${$1,2,3,4,5,6$}.

$f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}$({$b$})$=$

{$4,5,6$}$\subset ${$1,2,3,4,5,6$}.

$f^{-1}(A \cup B)=$

$f^{-1}(${$a,b$}$)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)=$

$f^{-1}(${$a$}$)\cup f^{-1}(${$b$}$)=$

{$1,2,3,4,5,6$}.

Used: $f^{-1}(A \cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: Thanks. could you please address the second part of the question as well.

Comment: Cosmic.$f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(${a}$)$ is the inverse image (a set) of the set A. If $f$ were one to one $f^1(a)=x$ one element of the domain $X$.Makes sense?

Comment: can't we define the inverse image of an element 'a' in the above (many-one) mapping given in the question?

Comment: I would use $f^{-1}(a)=x$, if $f$ is one to one , both $a,x$ are elements. $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $f$. $f^{-1}(${$a$}$)= D$, where {$a$},$D$ are sets for many to one.See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image